# Loading xml from .jar

Tags: java, xml, ant, jar

I'm trying to load .xml file from .jar (made by ant builder.xml) but got an exception.

Code from my ant build.xml:

[image: ant builder code]

Code from my class:

```
try {
xml = new File(this.getClass().getResource("/TaskData.xml").getFile());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
```

Exception I got:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\agent_000\Desktop\....file:\C:\Users\agent_000\Desktop\%d1%85%d1%83\build\sample.jar!\TaskData.xml (
```

Why it can't find a .xml file?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is the file actually in the jar? (open it with winrar or whatever)

Comment: @flkes according to mybuild.xml (which is ant file) a sample.jar is creating and yes, TaskData.xml in this .jar.

Comment: @flkes nope, same exception. Is something wrong in build.xml maybe?

Comment: Do not post your XML as an image.  Copy the actual text into your question.

Comment: The getFile() method of URL **does not** convert the URL to a file and **does not** return a valid file name.  Use `new File(url.toURI())` to convert a URL to a File.

Answer (score 0):

you can do like this

```
    URL url = new URL("jar:file:/path--to-your Jar !/TaskData.xml");
    InputStream is = url.openStream();
    System.out.println(is);

    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
    System.out.println(reader.readLine());
```

Or ask the ClassLoader to return an InputStream for the resource instead via getResourceAsStream:

```
InputStream in = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/TaskData.txt"); 
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
```

Comment: Thanks for answer! But i need to create a "File" class, so my class can parse it

Comment: you can try like,    File tempFile = File.createTempFile(prefix, suffix);
    tempFile.deleteOnExit();
    FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(tempFile);
    IOUtils.copy(in, out);
    return tempFile;